# Applying SVD in Sparse Matrices

Tags: python, svd

What factors should be considered while doing singular value decomposition (svd) on sparse matrices?

it is a very sparse matrix.I have done missing imputation using 0. do i need some other technique? The code is listed below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.preprocessing  import Normalizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

r_cols = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating','xcx']
data = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/ua.test', sep='\t', names=r_cols, usecols=['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating'], encoding='latin-1')
dtm = data.pivot(index='movie_id', columns='user_id', values='rating').fillna(0)
np.savetxt("pivot.csv", dtm, delimiter=",")

#without matrix factoriztion
cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(dtm, dtm)
np.savetxt("foo13.csv", cosine_sim, delimiter=",")

#with matrix factoriztion
lsa = TruncatedSVD(200, algorithm = 'arpack')
dtm_lsa = lsa.fit_transform(dtm)
dtm_lsa = Normalizer(copy = False).fit_transform(dtm_lsa)
similarity = np.asarray(np.asmatrix(dtm_lsa)*np.asmatrix(dtm_lsa).T)
np.savetxt("foo12.csv", similarity, delimiter=",")
```

Feel free to point out if I have missed any issues.